# Highchart export is calling events

Tags: highcharts

I'm having this problem. I'm using the load and setExtremes events on my chart.

When I click on the export button, all then event are lauched.

The events are causing some undesired behavior.

I would like to disable the events calling on export.

Is this posible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use chartOptions and disable chart -> events http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#exporting.chartOptions